# Unix is not printing the output I expect, even though the code is correct

Tags: unix, awk

my code is not printing the 6th line even though it passes the condition. actually it is not showing because the 6th line last field is 100. if i change to 99 it works perfectly.
how do i solve it?

code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {if (tolower($4) == "sangamithra" && $5>=90 && $6>=90 || $6==100) {print;}} END{}' last
```

input:

```
1|Latha|Third|Vikas|90|91
2|Neethu|Second|Meridian|92|94
3|Sethu|First|DAV|96|98
4|Theekshana|Second|DAV|97|96
5|Teju|First|Sangamithra|92|94
6|Theekshitha|Second|Sangamithra|99|100
```

output:

```
5|Teju|First|Sangamithra|92|94 
6|Theekshitha|Second|Sangamithra|99|100
```

Comment: Moreover, what is the awk version, and your OS? With nawk/mawk/gawk, I get line 5 & 6

Comment: i am using a online bash compiler

Comment: You can still run `command -v awk` and `awk --version` and probably `uname -a` to obtain the requested diagnostics.

Comment: Your code _does_ print the sixth line for me. Demo: https://ideone.com/eLYsJy Please provide a [mre].